# MS Bot framework i want to put a form builder in an open conversation

Tags: forms, chat, bots, botframework

I want to start Form conversation chat in Microsoft Bot framework.

```
if(user says hello)
{
reply = what u want to listen hi or hello
if(user says order)
{
reply= start a formbuilder.form with order form workflow
}
if(user says hello)
{
reply= hello
}
}
```

My problem is the first thing i do always works 
example: if i say first chat line as order it starts order form but it never goes to the normal conversation mode even if the form ends.

if i start hi then it always goes in hi mode never goes or create order form on typing order.

Need it to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to end your conversation when you are in a dialog or a conversation flow ends.

```
context.Done<object>(new object());
```

or

```
 context.Done(true);
```

do let me know if you need any help further

Comment: Thanks Manoj but it didnt help i will share a better version now
<code>  if (activity.Text == "order")
                {
                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(OrderDetails.BuildForm)));

                   
                }
                else
                {
                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
                }<code>

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you want start specific dialogs while triggering different words like `"hollo"` for greeting dialog, `"order"` for form dialog.

I think there are two methods to achieve this in C#:

- You can leverage Recognize intents to implement LUIS, which can identify your users' intent from their spken or textual input, or utterances. Trigger specific dialogs for each LUIS intent.

  For  this solution you can refer to the official document [Recognize intents and entities with LUIS using a prebuilt domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-luis-dialogs) for details, and refer to https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-LUIS for a sample for your reference.
- You also can build [Global message handlers using scorables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-scorable-dialogs) in your bot application for yourself. With which, you can route users to certain fuctionality by using words like "help," "cancel," or "start over" in the middle of a conversation when the bot is expecting a different response.

  Please refer to https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-GlobalMessageHandlers for the sample for this solution.

Hope it helps.